# Invoke ffprobe from resources: Bad IL format

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, ffprobe

I am trying to invoke the `ffprobe.exe` file from the resources in Visual Studio. I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030956/4118280) answer on SO and tried to apply it to ffprobe. But I cannot load the bytes to assembly. But my code throws an `System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL Format`.

I googled the error message and found that it normally indicates that the binary is corrupt. I made sure that the loaded bytes are identical to the bytes of the `ffprobe.exe` file from my resources, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645015/4118280) answer suggested. I wrote the bytes to a file and then compared it with the original file using the [`comp`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/software-to-compare-files-and-folders/32167001-2e60-43f1-b326-0768e1d6e4f2?auth=1) command.
When calling the `ffprobe.exe` file through the command line, it works perfectly. So I am sure it is not corrupt.

Here is what I tried:

```
object ob = Properties.Resources.ffprobe;
var ffprobeBytes = (byte[])ob;      // ffprobeBytes is identical to ffprobe.exe in resources
var ffprobeAssembly = Assembly.Load(ffprobeBytes);     // this line throws the Exception

var ffprobeEntry = ffprobeAssembly.EntryPoint;
var ffProbeObject = ffprobeAssembly.CreateInstance(ffprobeEntry.Name);
string[] parameters = { filePath, "=show_streams", "-print_format xml", "-loglevel fatal" };
var result = ffprobeEntry.Invoke(ffProbeObject, parameters)
```

The `BuildAction` of the resource file is `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to output directory` is set to `Copy always`.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this Exception?

Comment: Assembly.Load(byte[]) can only work on .NET assemblies that contain pure IL.  Clearly ffprobe.exe is not, you must deploy it as a file and use Process.Start()

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you :)